# does all of the files involved has been written finish after the result of git pull printed?

Tags: git, shell, git-pull

I wrote a shell script, which can get the lastest code from git and then restart the program.The code  logic is showed as follows:

`git pull origin master
the_command_of_restart`

But i found, although the git command executed successfully, after program was restart it still ran old code.It seemed that after `git pull`, the git repository had been updated finished, but the files involved with the repository had not been written finish.
If what i guess is true, how can i execute the restart command after all modifed file being written finish.

Answer (score 0):

If two pipelines are separated by `&&', the second pipeline is  executed only  after the  first  succeeds  (returns a zero status).

Comment: I think it not the problem of shell. I'm afraid that the command of `git pull` only concern about updating the git repository. The change of local files is dealed with asynchronously after the git repository updated successfully.

Comment: Are you sure that the conflicts have been cleanly resolved? I'd be very surprised to find that `git-merge` daemonized to resolve files asynchonrously

Comment: It has no conflicts.And the `git pull ` executed successfully, i could see the result of it.

Comment: Have you tried `git fetch --all && git merge origin/master && the_command_of_restart`?

Answer (score 0):

I think I have made a mistake. After running the command of `git pull`, files will be wirtten over. And this command is credible.